# Automatic creation of Ingress resources with Knative

Tags: kubernetes, knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing, knative-functions

### Is it possible to have Knative automatically create K8s Ingress resources?

Hello all,
Based on the following lines from [documentation](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/creating-services/), I was wondering if I can have Knative automatically create the Ingress resources for my service? I haven't found details on this in the documentation.

```
After the service has been created, Knative performs the following tasks:

- Creates a new immutable revision for this version of the app.
- Performs network programming to create a route, ingress, service, and load balancer for your app.
- Automatically scales your pods up and down based on traffic, including to zero active pods.
```

Example:
Taking the Service and Ingress definition below, would it be possible to abstract away the Ingress yaml and have knative take care of its creation automatically for services?

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: knative
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nonprofit
      annotations:
        queue.sidecar.serving.knative.dev/resourcePercentage: "10"
        autoscaling.knative.dev/class: "kpa.autoscaling.knative.dev"
        autoscaling.knative.dev/target: "40"
        autoscaling.knative.dev/min-scale: "1"
        autoscaling.knative.dev/max-scale: "3"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-java
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 50m
              memory: 100M
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 200M
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: TARGET
              value: "Sunny Day"
  traffic:
  - tag: latest
    latestRevision: true
    percent: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: knative-hello-ingress
  namespace: knative
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: "hello.knative"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "ingress-generic"
  rules:
  - host: "hello-knative.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello
            port:
              number: 80
```

Thank you,

Haven't tried anything as I haven't found details in the documentation regarding this.

Comment: Have you checked this document on [Configuring Services Custom ingress class](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/ingress-class/). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat Thanks for the response. Yes I have. I neglected to mention in the question that I am using an nginx ingress controller for access to the cluster, and the Ingress I wrote in the question is essentially to have nginx controller reroute the requests to the Knative service

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the v1 Ingress API in Kubernetes does not have sufficient capabilities to express Knative's routing requirements.  Knative *does* support several ingress implementations (including Istio, Contour, and the Gateway API), but no one has written a plugin for the Nginx Ingress annotations.

Some of the capabilities that are missing from the Kubernetes Ingress API which are needed by Knative include:

- Backend traffic splits / weights
- Setting request headers to the backend server
- Requesting HTTP/2 or websockets protocol support

If you're willing to use bets software, the Gateway API plugin is mostly feature complete and should plug into a [variety of ingress providers](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/implementations/).  Unfortunately, Nginx does not appear to be on that list.